# Launch/access applications remotely in Delphi

Tags: delphi, remote-access

My Delphi 5 Windows software can link to my Point of Sale (POS.exe) application after creating an OLE object when the form is created:

```
procedure TForm1.SetupEposLink;
begin
  EposServer := CreateOLEObject('POS.Server');
  {Hide the Server}
  if HideLmPos then
    EposServer.InVisible;
end;
```

At the users request, items are then passed to it through methods such as:

```
EposServer.SetMemberDetails(FieldByName('Name').AsString,FieldByName('Member Id').AsString);

EposServer.SellItemAsString(ActCode,'1',FloatToStr(Price),BDate,BTime,RetValue);

EposServer.IsServerOn(Answer1);

EposServer.Visible;
```

This has never been an issue until now when the POS is installed on a terminal server for remote access, and the process simply times out when attempting to call one of these methods.

Will the application specifically need to be installed locally or is there a getaround I can used to create a better link to the location of the application?

many thanks

Comment: What is the exact error message you get when you try to call one of the OLE objects methods? The Client application is installed on the terminal server as well?

Comment: CreateOLEObject expects the POS.Server to be registered as a COM-Server on the computer your software runs on. So i think, your software and the (registered) POS.Server have to be on the same machine.

Comment: Have you read about and do you understand about DCOM Configuration (dcomcnfg)?

Comment: @Andreas; It should be possible to register and then configure secure remote access to an out-of-process server via DCOM, but it may not be possible to have it launch.

Answer (score 2):

You may need to configure DCOM. Check out the paragraph titled "Configuring DCOM on windows xp and windows server 2003"  [here](http://j-integra.intrinsyc.com/support/com/doc/remoteaccess.html).

I am not sure if DCOM can remotely launch your service, but it needs to be registered in both places, and you use DCOM Config to specify the machine that hosts the service.

Secondly you might want to check out the help for [ComObj.CreateRemoteComObject](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/ComObj.CreateRemoteComObject),

Comment: Thanks guys. I will look in to this DCOM as it sounds like the right idea. The POS.exe is infact running on a separate PC, but the user remotely connects to the main software which is trying to talk to it. Apologies for my lack of clarity as I'm dealing with this for a colleague. I will update accordingly after I look in to it further.

Comment: Be aware that DCOM can be very difficult to troubleshoot when it fails. Be prepared to spend some time learning how to troubleshoot DCOM issues when they occur.